# Only host can spawn object

Tags: unity, networking, multiplayer, first-person-shooter

I am currently making a multiplayer game however only the host has the capability to spawn projectiles.

```
[Command]
void CmdSpawnEgg()
{
    if (cam == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    GameObject instance = Instantiate(eggPrefab, transform.position + (transform.forward * offset), cam.rotation);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(instance);
}
```

//cam is the transform of the players camera and if its not the local player the camera is destroyed

[image: these are the settings for the network identity:]

The projectile is also a registered spawn-able prefab for the network manager

Comment: Try checking if `cam` is null on your client player. Or just check for `isLocalPlayer`

Comment: this was the problem i was destroying the camera if it wasnt the local player but that made the server unsure of where the bullet was supposed to come from

Comment: nice! glad you figured it out.